# Radical Bromination of a 1-isopropyl-4-methylcyclohexane

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, radicals

I'm considering a problem whereby 1-isopropyl-4-methylcyclohexane with the indicated stereochemistry shown undergoes radical bromination at the indicated position. I understand there are other products produced. However, if the radical initiator (not shown) extracts the hydrogen at the 4 position, then the bromine radical attacks, there will be two distinct products. However, I am having trouble determining if these molecules are chiral? Are they diastereomers to each other?

[image]

Also, as a follow up, how would you name these (reagent + two products) to indicate their stereochemistry?

Comment: No, they aren't chiral because of symmetry plane, they are cis/trans isomers

Comment: Mith is right. But that doesn't mean they're not diastereomers though :)

Answer (score 1):

They are not chiral because $\ce{C}-4$ is only considered to be bonded to 3 unique groups because the ring is completely symmetrical through $\ce{C}-1$ and $\ce{C}-4$.

As for naming these compounds, the reagent is simple: ***cis*-1-isopropyl-4-methylcyclohexane** (or ***cis*-1-(1-dimethylethyl)-4-methylcyclohexane** if you're a stickler for the rules).

The products are a little tricker. Let's start with the basics: it is **1-bromo-4-isopropyl-1-methylcylohexane**. Now to account for the steric relations of these substituents, label the reference substituent (labeled *r*) followed by a hyphen and the substituent locator number and name. The relative configuration of other substituents are then reported as cis (*c*) or trans (*t*) to the reference substituent.

This means that in the order that you present the products, their names are ***r*-1-bromo-*t*-4-isopropyl-1-methylcylohexane** and ***r*-1-bromo-*c*-4-isopropyl-1-methylcylohexane**.

[[Source](http://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/recommendations/CompleteDraft) - (page 1060)]

Comment: Do you have any references for the naming of the products with the r/s c/t nomenclature? I was trying to work these out myself but hit a brick wall. The only info I had was from March's Advanced Organic Chemistry, but the discussion was incredibly brief.

Comment: *"if you're a stickler for the rules"* - "isopropyl" is (probably) the preferred IUPAC name for $\ce{-CHMe2}$.

Comment: Yes, it is the preferred name. Maybe I should have said if you're a stickler for *systematic* names :)

Comment: @orthocresol The preferred prefix for $\ce{(CH3)2CH-{}}$ is “propan-2-yl”. The prefixes “isopropyl” and “1-methylethyl” may be used in general nomenclature. Besides, the stereodescriptors _cis_ and _trans_ are not used in preferred IUPAC names, but they may be used in general nomenclature.

Comment: @Loong in the source that I linked, *cis*-inositol is listed as a a preferred IUPAC name. I think *cis*-*trans* nomenclature is preferred less than other stereodsicriptors, but when they are not an option *cis* and *trans* are in fact used.